# Accessing a function inside of componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
componentDidMount(){

  logsAB(a,b){
    console.log(a,b);
  }
}

renderListItems(listItem,key){
  var x = '1';
  var y = '2';

  return (
    <li key={key}>
     <a href="#" className={key} onClick={() => this.logsAB(x,y)}>{blahblah.blah.foo}</a></li>


)
}
```

Am I wrong for trying to call upon a function inside of 'componentDidMount'? I figured since componentDidMount fires after the html loads, the click handler should fire once its loaded. Thus making the function available.

Comment: You're not calling a function inside of `componentDidMount`, you're defining one.

Comment: @dosebot can you confirm if my answer helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `componentDidMount` is a function on your main Component class. Functions inside `componentDidMount` are only scoped to that function, unless you bind them to the `this` scope, as follows:

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.logsAB = (a, b) => {
    console.log(a, b);
  }
}

renderListItems(listItem, key){
  var x = '1';
  var y = '2';

  return (
    <li key={key}>
     <a href="#" className={key} onClick={() => this.logsAB(x, y)}>
       {blahblah.blah.foo}
     </a>
    </li>
  )
}
```

That will work, but does not follow normal react conventions, rather do the following:

```
logsAB(a, b){
  console.log(a, b);
}

renderListItems(listItem, key){
  var x = '1';
  var y = '2';

  return (
    <li key={key}>
     <a href="#" className={key} onClick={() => this.logsAB(x, y)}>
       {blahblah.blah.foo}
     </a>
    </li>
  )
}
```

The above code places the function `logsAB` on the Component scope, letting it get called via `this.logsAB`. `componentDidMount` is not required to set a function on the Component.